# upgrade path from acegi-0.5.2 to spring-security

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm migrating from acegi to spring-security plugin and am running into a BadCredentials  problem.  I have existing users in the database with encrypted unsalted md5 hashes.

If I understand correctly, acegi-0.5.2 used no salt and newest spring-security has mandatory salt.  So I am confused about the upgrade path.

This seems like it would be a fairly common upgrade scenario.  Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: They differ because the password is salted by `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder`.

Comment: I believe you are saying that in the acegi 0.5.2 plugin, there was no salt was used?( what is the key property ), and in the latest spring-security there is a mandatory salt.  What's the correct upgrade path?

Comment: This was my fix

grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations=1


link from 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533477/grails-spring-security-plugin-migrate-user-passwords-from-1-2-7-3-to-2-0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this wasn't a salting issue but instead the hash was getting hashed and hashed again.

grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations=1

was the fix for me.

Found from [Grails Spring Security Plugin Migrate User Passwords from 1.2.7.3 to 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533477/grails-spring-security-plugin-migrate-user-passwords-from-1-2-7-3-to-2-0)